# How to get json key and value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am returning a json as shown below

```
{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}
```

I am trying to get each element key and value:

```
..
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data['jobtitel']);
});
```

I am getting `undefined` in alert. WHY? I tried `data.jobtitel`, i tried loop but no success..

Comment: first u need to convert that json to array then have to try data.jobtitel

Comment: JSON is string and u want to access there that then u must have to convert...

Comment: @swan, $.parseJSON is not always available in every browser.. what to do ?

Comment: if u add jquery then $.parseJSON will work...otherwise u have to use pure javascript JSON converter JSON.eval(jsonstring)

Comment: Is `jobtitel` a typo?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
//By using jquery json parser    
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(obj['jobtitel']);

//By using javasript json parser
var t = JSON.parse('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(t['jobtitel'])
```

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydd2H/1/)

> As of **jQuery 3.0**, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use
> the native JSON.parse method instead.
>
> Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: This is not documented enough. The ability to use json['KeyAsString']. Really great. Thank you.

Comment: How would I resolve Entwickler to jobtitel? Is there anythind native or do I have to write my own code?

Answer (score 24):

you have parse that `Json` string using `JSON.parse()`

```
..
}).done(function(data){
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj.jobtitel);
});
```

Comment: Simplified: JSON.parse(data).jobtitle

Answer (score 13):

```
var data = {"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}

var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parsedData.name);
alert(parsedData.skills);
alert(parsedData.jobtitel);
alert(parsedData.res_linkedin);
```

Comment: This is how you do it in javascript.

Answer (score 5):

For getting key

```
var a = {"a":"1","b":"2"};
var keys = []
for(var k in a){
  keys.push(k)
}
```

For getting value.

```
var a = {"a":"1","b":"2"};
var values = []
for(var k in a){
  values.push(a[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/v8aWF/

Worked out a fiddle. Do check it out

```
(function() {
    var oJson = {
        "name": "", 
        "skills": "", 
        "jobtitle": "Entwickler", 
        "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"
    }
    alert(oJson.jobtitle);
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach instead of using JSON.parse

```
 success: function(response){
     var resdata = response;
     alert(resdata['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `data` not contains what you think it contains - check it.

```js
let data={"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"};

console.log( data["jobtitel"] );
console.log( data.jobtitel );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to get a JSON key and value in JavaScript:

```
var dt = JSON.stringify(data).replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
if (dt) {
  var result = jQuery.parseJSON(dt);
  var val = result.YOUR_OBJECT_NAME;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.