# Extract few key value pair from JSON object to another JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I've got an JSON object like that:

```
var storeOriginalList = '[{"Store_Id" : "1932","Store_Name" : "1 Sale A Day12","KeywordURL" : "1-Sale-A-Day1234","Category" : "Stores"},{"Store_Id" : "1171","Store_Name" : "100 Day Loans","KeywordURL" : "100-Day-Loans","Category" : "Stores"}]'
```

I want to extract only `Store_Id`, `Store_Name` and also make an another new JSON object.

My question is, can I do it without looping. If yes, then please provide a sample code.

Comment: yes it's possible, but what you have done so far?

Comment: How about you give it a try, and ask a *specific* question if/when you run into trouble.

Comment: Refer to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/18910983/3008050

Comment: i searched but couldn't get the extracting few set of pairs out of another with out looping. And my question is clear. "My question is can i do it without looping."

Comment: And @Girish, u expect every one to write what all they have done before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *reasonably* do it without looping, no. You could try with a regular expression, but A) That would be looping, too, in the processing of the regex; and B) Using regular expressions to manipulate non-regular things like JSON [or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is prone to failure.

Here are tools you could use in your solution:

- [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - which is what loops for you
- [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)