# Can't access JSON attribute.

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
alert(fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')  
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()['description']
    }))
```

I was expecting `Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!` but apparently, this is just an Object?

According to the other answers I've checked, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript), this should work perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

```
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
})
.then(function(data) {
   return data.description
})
.then(function(description) {
    alert(description)
 })
```

Comment: How many open brackets/braces are before this? There are 2 brackets on the 3rd line, but the other `then` statement only 1, for example, and no semi-colon.

Comment: Still better than callback hell. BTW you could use arrow functions if don't care much about old browsers. `fetch(blah).then(x => x.json()).then(data => alert(data.description))` - no brackets at all :)

Comment: So there's no way to get the data out of there? I want to save this as a variable and use it elsewhere in my code.

Comment: You can save promise as a variable say `gettingData = fetch().then(x => x.json())` and use it later still knowing it is a Promise `gettingData.then(data => /* do something with data*/)`. Plz read this question to get better understanding of what the problem with async code is about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

You can access the description as shown below.

To save the value and use it later, you can use states (aka Component States).

```
.then(function(response) {
    var resJson = response.json();
    var des = resJson['description'];
    this.setState(
         { 
             description: des 
         }
    )

    }))
```

You can define your states in the React Component like so:

```
class MyClass extends Component {

    state = {
        description: ""
    }
```

And retreive the state like so:

```
var currentState = this.state.description;
```