# How to correctly parse JSON object returned from django response to template into data attribute

Tags: javascript, python, django

I wasn't able to find similar topic in google.

I return simple object into the django template through views

views:

```
return render(request, 'mainPage.html', {
    'obj': getObj()
})

def getObj():
    path = '/home/myPage' + 'obj.json'

    fd = open( path, 'r')
    obj = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    return json.dumps(obj)
```

template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="obj" data-obj="{{ obj }}">
```

and JS:

```
var obj = JSON.parse( $('#obj').data('obj') );
console.log( obj );
```

I see in the console the right result:

```
{
    "2018": {
        "First": {
            "obj1": "4",
            "obj2": "231",
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to refer to this obj by console.log(obj ['2018']); it returns undefined

Will be thankful for your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get json key and value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like obj.json is already a JSON file. There is no need to call `json.dumps` on the data after reading it. Just pass `obj` directly.

Also, you will need to disable auto escaping in the template by outputting it as `{{ obj|safe }}`.