# How to store data from REST API response in a variable?

Tags: javascript, rest, npm

Say this is the response

```
{
  "symbol": "LTCBTC",
  "bidPrice": "4.00000000",
  "bidQty": "431.00000000",
  "askPrice": "4.00000200",
  "askQty": "9.00000000"
}
```

how would I store only 4.00000200 from the askPrice as a variable, so I can perform math on later?

The answers in the other question do not explain how to store the response. They explain how to get parts of it once you have already stored it.

Comment: How are you getting the response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get json key and value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @stealththeninja https://pastebin.com/M7Ezt98p

Comment: Please consider using a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It helps everyone: the person asking, those answering, and people who search for this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is async, you need to use async / await, or a callback to get the data after it has been received:

```
async function getData(){
    var obtdata = await binanceRest.bookTicker({symbol: 'BTCUSDT'})
    var symbol = obtdata.symbol
    var bidPrice = obtdata.bidPrice
    var bidQty = obtdata.bidQty
    var askPrice = obtdata.askPrice
    var askQty = obtdata.askQty

    console.log(askPrice);
}
```

Using callback function:

```
 binanceRest.bookTicker({symbol: 'BTCUSDT'},(obtdata)=>{
    var symbol = obtdata.symbol
    var bidPrice = obtdata.bidPrice
    var bidQty = obtdata.bidQty
    var askPrice = obtdata.askPrice
    var askQty = obtdata.askQty

    console.log(askPrice);
})
```

Comment: Is there any reason why console.log(askPrice) returns nothing? This is the code right now https://pastebin.com/CzP2yb9P

Comment: @blahahaaahahaa Can you log obtdata and let me know the output?

Comment: @blahahaaahahaa Try the callback version if async / await isn't working.

Comment: obtdata also has no output. It is not that it says undefined. There is just no console log. I will try the callback version once I figure out how to do it.

Comment: All right I tried the called back version. This is my code https://pastebin.com/SS2BdZxq. It says the promise is pending and obtdata is not defined.

Comment: Oh. I figured it out. I had to use getData() and not console.log(obtdata).

Answer (score 1):

You can get your response in a variable like this. you can fetch every data of resopnse in a obtdata

```
var obtdata = { 
  "symbol": "LTCBTC",
  "bidPrice": "4.00000000",
  "bidQty": "431.00000000",
  "askPrice": "4.00000200",
  "askQty": "9.00000000"
}

var symbol = obtdata.symbol
var bidPrice =obtdata.bidPrice
var bidQty =obtdata.bidQty
var askPrice =obtdata.askPrice
var askQty =obtdata.askQty
```

For more information you can go this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript)

Comment: This is my code currently https://pastebin.com/Rr5JP8mn. Do you know why my variables are undefined?

Comment: You don't have value in your variable thats why undefined showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object response object property by object_name.property

Like `let price = response.askPrice`