# Access value "firstName" in object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`console.log(participants);` results in:

[image]

I am trying to access the firstName of each "participant":

```
const entries = Object.entries(participants);

entries.map((participant) => {
  console.log(participant.firstName);
});
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: see this hope this will hep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript

Comment: Consider reading the basic docs related to javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Apply map directly on participants array list.
participants.map(x=> console.log(x.firstName));

Comment: @VimalPatel thanks for the suggestion, however that returns `participants.map is not a function`. I feel like I tried a kind of combinations but will go through the readings now.

Comment: I was about to submit an answer when the question was closed. Anyways, don't use Object.entries() and apply the map like this: participants.Pm2bnmV.map(participant => console.log(participant.firstName)); Because it looks like the participants variable has a property that has the array. If change that structure so the participants variable is just an array you can do what Vimal Patel said.

Comment: Thanks, Dillan. That solved it.